# converting URL to Action Link @url.action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have problem with IIS does not read the URL.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

My project is on Asp.net MVC
I have used a Jqx grid on my project but the grid does not load data on IIS.

How can I convert the URL  to Action Link  @url.action, so the IIS can read?

My URL on my grid.

url: "/Home/GetIMScompinfo?CompanyName=" + $("#CompanyName").val() + "&StoreName=" + $("#StoreName").val() + "&ComputerName=" + $("#ComputerName").val() + params

url: "/Home/GetSubItems?scopeId=" + id

Comment: You need to share more code and more explanation around what you are trying to do and what issue you are facing.

Comment: What do you mean by "Action Link"?

Comment: my project is on Asp.net MVC, i am using JQXGrid library for my table. the data on the table are loaded throught the URL above, but the IIS does not read this URL, as i have google i have to convert this URL to Action Link  @url.action

Comment: IIS won't not read the url unless the url is incorrect. The incorrect means wrong host name, wrong uri structure, wrong controller or action name, wrong parameter of action. However, even the wrong url, IIS still can get the request and response useful error message and code like 404, 405, 500. So what do you mean IIS doesn't read URL?

Comment: If you want to send all data in grid, you can use  `@Html.BeginForm()` or `@Ajax.BeginForm()` to send grid.

Comment: the error is: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable).  i have google and the solutions is to use @ url.action link, but my URL is with parameters and don't know how to converti it to @ url.action.

Answer (score 0):

> url: "/Home/GetIMScompinfo?CompanyName=" + $("#CompanyName").val() + "&StoreName=" + $("#StoreName").val() + "&ComputerName=" + $("#ComputerName").val() + params
> url: "/Home/GetSubItems?scopeId=" + id

I don't know what is the difference between the two getting the value. So I give the sample script for the first url.

```
<button class="btn-class" id="press" type="button" onclick="changeHref1()">Genrate first url</button>



<script type="text/javascript">
function changeHref1() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("About","Home")';
    var company = $('#CompanyName').val();
    var store = $('#StoreName').val();
    var computer = $('#ComputerName').val();
    window.location.href = url + '?CompanyName=' + company + '&StoreName=' + store + '&ComputerName=' + computer;
}

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: it's not a button, the URL is the source data to load the grid.   so this URL load data to grid automatically on run.   url: "/Home/GetIMScompinfo?CompanyName=" + $("#CompanyName").val() + "&StoreName=" + $("#StoreName").val() + "&ComputerName=" + $("#ComputerName").val() + params

Comment: If so, why not add a model to contain these properties, then pass the model to view and use foreach to load model data?